# Significance of a 1 state Hidden Markov Model

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, pattern-recognition

I've been training different observation sequences to obtain different HMMs corresponding to each observed data. Something intriguing is that I get one observation sequence represented by 1 state. What does that represent? Does this mean that it's somewhat repeating a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer. If an HMM is described by only one state, it would definitely mean that the same process is repeating itself as time goes on. For example, as I've been working with gesture recognition using HMMs, let's consider the walking movement of a person. The proper number of states that would represent this kind of gesture would consists of at least 2 states. That is, one state for the left leg and one state for the right one. Naturally, this HMM will be an ergodic one as the transition probabilities moves back and froth between the two states.

But now, if the walking movement would be represented by merely one state, this implies that the person is doing exactly the same movement over time. And in the context of statistical analysis, this kind of single state representation would lack statistical significance. It is better to check another model that is close enough (i.e. having a likelihood) of the single state. Thus 2 states would be a better representation of the walking event in this case.